# Spring MVC simple case

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans

Trying to understand a sample code...
I am returning a modelview successfully from my AthuenticationController like this

```
modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home/");
....
return modelAndView;
```

and my browser url is changed to `/home/` but its showing a `404 page`

I have a HomePageController and it has methods

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadHome
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/main")
    public String reloadHome
```

but System.out.println("Message") is not executing in any of the above methods.
When authenticated I want to load a home.jsp page? It is in WEB-INF/jsp/...

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

login.html page thats from WEB-INF/jsp/ is loading fine

Here is the update Now it is opeining WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp page in browser but the url is still the old one...

Comment: provide your servlet mapping code from `web.xml` and viewResolver from your `spring-servlet.xml`

Comment: and servlet mapping from web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadHome
```

Comment: that is how you ma a url string to controller method. Check you typing in the url correctly(with or without trailing slash?); also check your app is deploying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home/");
....
return modelAndView;
```

try this one :

```
modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
....
return modelAndView;
```